What are examples of multi-clan political systems being overthrown by an individual who united them?
Edit 2: I apologize for clearly not including enough information and not entirely understanding the structure of this website. Additional information: 1. Clans is used as the name for these non-state groups as they are often from one Family name or have sworn to that families name. Think feudal lords. 2. Due to the unique structure of both a separated and conglomerate political group, determining course of action for coup was difficult to determine without examples. Plot relevant details have not been included, just basic worldbuilding around the situation and asking for examples of resolutions found in history. 3. This group is more akin to a massive mercenary organization with political power than a nation-state.
In my world, one story I am telling is following a lady who discovers that her heritage means that she has a claim to be chieftain over one of the major political groups in my world. They exist as a number of clans each led by a sub-chieftain spread across the continent taking small modular communities near most major cities. The group, the Bruth'ra, are led by a solitary chieftain out of the main city in the north where eight of the clans have gathered together. The outer clans tend to be nomadic, while the main city has not moved in years.
The MC Eirina was told that she possessed a historical power to access the memories of "the Kings" of the Bruth'ra throughout history. (For reference when a chieftain dies while still in power, he is classified a King). These kings named the MC's clan that she hails from, and told her that she is meant to be Chieftain. In order to do so, she would need to convince the seven leaders of the outer clans, and the current Chieftain to stand down. Either that, or violently overthrow the government.
How could I approach this coup with the least amount of damage to the people and Eirina's reputation? Mainly, is there historical or fictional coups of a similar vain I can look at?
Edit for clarity: This is a minor plot point in the entire story and is mainly required to get MC into position for later aspects of the story. I am wanting to base it on historical contexts so that it can flow better.

I'm sorry, but isn't this question asking the community to write the plot of your story? Step 1: Convince chieftain A. Step 2: Convince chieftain B. Step 3: Convince Chieftain C. Step 4: Convince chieftain D. Step 5: Now she has a majority of 4 to 3. Have a frank conversation with the Top Chieftain and tell him he has lost majority support. Happens all the time in political parties and parliamentary democracies. Just for example, how did Boris Johnson become Prime Minister of the UK?

If you're looking specifically for historical examples, History.SE may have you covered.

It seems you are using clan to refer to a non-state society rather then "a close knit group of interrelated families".  If you read acoup's how-to-raise-a-tribal-army-in-pre-roman-europe I think you would find it informative to construct more historically accurate societies.It also contains examp0le of something close to what you are after: Vercingetorix.

This question seems to be focused on writing the plot of your world, not building its background, which makes it off-topic for this site.  As @Cadence notes, History.SE exists specifically to answer questions about history.  There are also sites for SciFi/Fantasy and Literature if you are interested in fictional examples.  However, all of those sites (and this one) require prior research.  Try typing "bloodless coup" into your search engine and two of the top results are the Wikipedia pages for "Nonviolent revolution" and "List of coups and coup attempts".

There are generally two ways that this will happen and one much rarer way:
1: Greater external threat.
This is the most bloodless one (from an internal point of view) - that is - there is an existential threat that unites all the disparate factions and they agree that the lady, with her prior knowledge from all the previous entities is the best person to lead them to victory.
Examples of where this has happened - The first Gulf War, The US and Afghanistan against the Soviets, Spartans, Athenians and Thebians against the Persians etc.
2: Making an example out of one clan who refused to join and demonstrating the value in joining.
This is the classic Plata o plomo (Lead or Gold) ultimatum - either you join us, work with us and profit from it - or you will be destroyed.
To limit the destruction to the clans, only one needs to be made an example of - who refuses to bend the knee - Even better if the example can be limited to the leadership of the Clan. There are probably historic examples of this - probably Ghenghis Khan and other Warlords who united a country.
Bonus third way
Joan of Arc is probably the closest to what you would want to use - that is someone who makes the other clans believe that they are divinely chosen.
The mechanism for this could have several layers in your world:
1: Ancient wisdom - if they have the knowledge of previous kings, then it is conceivable they would know things that are unknown or forgotten - things that could help prove their divine right to rule.
2: Main-Character syndrome. If they miraculously survived something that should otherwise be unsurvivable (walking through a hail of arrows without armor and not being scratched) - again, something that points to divine intervention.
3: Competence - If you tell people to do something that sounds silly, but you sincerely believe it will work and lead by example, people will follow you. If it actually works and is successful, people will really follow you. If your character demonstrates competence, this will make others want to join them.
4: Leading, without requiring the others to give up their power. If I am a chief and can do pretty much whatever I want to do, why would I give this up? If the agreement of uniting the Clans can be done so in such a way that there is no requirement to cede any power (or at least the Clans remain almost complete autonomy, with only some well-define obligations) - then this can be somewhat acceptable.
